# File extension for Zend Framework layouts

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework

In Zend Framework we can change the file extension of view files from phtml to php by adding following code to controller.

```
$this->getHelper('viewRenderer')->setViewSuffix('php');
```

But how to change the file extension for layout files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested, but likely through

- [`Zend_Layout::setViewSuffix()`](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_Layout/Zend_Layout.html#setViewSuffix) - *Set layout view script suffix* and
- [`Zend_Layout_Controller_Action_Helper_Layout::getLayoutInstance()`](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_Controller/Zend_Controller_Action/Zend_Layout_Controller_Action_Helper_Layout.html#getLayoutInstance)

Try

```
$this->getHelper('layout')->getLayoutInstance()->setViewSuffix('php');
```

You can also try

```
Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->setViewSuffix('php');
```

There is also [`Zend_Application_Resource_Layout`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html#zend.application.available-resources.layout), so you can likely setup the `viewSuffix` from your application.ini as well when using `Zend_Application`, e.g. something like

```
resources.layout.viewSuffix = php;
```

Comment: Thanks, $this->getHelper('layout')->setViewSuffix('php'); it worked for me.